# krumo()/dpm() not working

Tags: theming, forms, debugging

I have a custom module and a template to alter the appearance of my node submission forms, á la [these instructions](http://drupal.org/node/1092122).

My module consists of three functions:

- A `hook_form_alter()` that works fine
- A `hook_theme()` that doesn't do anything but return an array, even if you enter other code before `return` (not sure if this is by design)
- A `hook_preprocess_HOOK()` that is currently empty

`dpm()` doesn't seem to do anything in `hook_preprocess_HOOK()`, although `krumo()` on the same variables *sort of* works. It sets a Drupal message that reads `Array: [n] items` but can't be expanded or inspected at all.

In my template, `print_r($form);` prints out the form array as expected. `dpm('self-aware roomba');` sets a Drupal message of "self-aware roomba" as expected. but `dpm($form)`; does nothing and throws no error.

Everything except my `hook_form_alter()` is exactly as it appears in the linked tutorial. I even tried pulling out the entire `hook_form_alter()` to see if it works without it; it doesn't.

What could be causing `dpm()`/`krumo()` to fail silently?

Comment: is Devel module installed? dpm() comes from Devel module

Comment: Yes, Devel is installed. `dpm('self-aware roomba');` wouldn't work otherwise and `krumo()` wouldn't return `Array: [n] items`, it would just cause a fatal PHP error, which would cause my logs to not be empty.

Comment: so please place your code in your question and let me re-produce the errors ;)

Comment: It is exactly identical to the code in the linked tutorial. It's a bit long to post it all in the question window. All the code is here: http://drupal.org/node/1092122

Comment: in which function (where) you are trying dpm()?

Comment: Are connected as admin, or did you allow "anonymous" role to use devel in the permissions ?

Comment: In the question, I mentioned trying it in all three functions and in the template.

Comment: I'm connected as admin.

Comment: I can't find `hook_form_alter` in your linked tutorial and in other function there is no any $form variable. emmm, am I miss something?

Comment: hook_form_alter() is something I added, but I removed it entirely for debugging and removing it had no effect.

Comment: adding new hooks in your module require clearing cache. do you try clearing cache?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4615/discussion-between-mohammad-ali-akbari-and-beth)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean in the comment about `hook_theme()` returning an array even if there is code before the `return` statement. Functions **do** return the argument of the `return` statement. That is what normally happens in PHP.

Comment: What I meant was, it doesn't run the code that comes before the return() statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have run into an issue where `dpm()` and some other messages were eaten up by a 404 request in the background.

*Explanation:*

If `dpm()` or `drupal_set_message()` is called before the messages are printed out with `theme_status_messages()`, then you get to see them on the same page.

If `dpm()` or `drupal_set_message()` is called after `theme_status_messages()`, then those messages are delayed in `$_SESSION` until the next request that does `theme_status_messages()`.

Some types of requests **do NOT** trigger `theme_status_messages()`. E.g. a form submit will only do the form processing, and then do a redirect, so the messages remain in the `$_SESSION`.

Also, it will only trigger on requests by the same visitor/client (this is why it is saved in session, which is client specific).

However, some requests that happen in the background do trigger `theme_status_messages()`, and can eat up your messages.

In my case this were requests to missing images, which resulted in full-blown html 404 pages WITH messages (and I did not get to see any of this, obviously).

**Solution:**

The solution was to activate the "fast 404" feature.

- [Change notice 1296384](https://drupal.org/node/1296384) explaining this newly introduced feature.
- [Drupal 7 default.settings.php](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x:/sites/default/default.settings.php) you might want to copy some code from here.

Comment: That's a really nice piece of debugging, well done. My issue was that I had an SVG file 404ing, which wasn't covered in the default file extensions. Thanks for a great answer!

Comment: Major up-votes for your research, @zhilevan! Fast 404 didn't solve this for me for some reason, but this was definitely the cause, as fixing the 404s instantly caused my dpm() to start showing up.

Answer (score 1):

test this my friend

```
ob_start();
krumo($yourparameter);
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
drupal_set_message($output);
```

Comment: This works but I get several versions of the same log message. If I understand correctly, all this is doing is collecting together the output and then rendering it via a php buffer? Is that right?

Comment: @marblegravy yes ,right